# Bind jQuery plugin on element which doesn't yet exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I can bind an event to an element which doesn't exist at initial page load as follows:

```
$('#myParentElement').on('click','a.myClass',function(){
   alert( 'success' );
});
```

How can a plugin similarly be bound?  For instance, the below will not work if `a.myClass` exists within a handlebars template, or any DOM which doesn't exist upon initial page load.  If this answer is plugin specific, please limit to the https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ plugin.

```
$('#myParentElement a.myClass').editable();
```

Why I am doing this....  I have a bunch of elements such as `<p data-handlebar="one">one</p>`, `<p data-handlebar="two">two</p>`, etc, and upon being clicked, will display a dialog with some content specified by the template.  Within each template, I have several identical elements I wish to apply xeditable to.

Comment: You can't without user interaction or simply without any event trigger.

Comment: Does your framework have an init function that you could use? eg. most frameworks have somekind of onWidgetCreated or onComponentRendered function or some kind of code that runs as soon as the widget is created. You could add your binding code there.

Comment: @Shanimal  No framework being used.  Why can't it be done just with JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: You can look into mutation observers or you can poll and check to see if the element is loaded.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7  For my specific need, the user clicks an element, and a dialog is displayed with content using handlebars.  I suppose I can apply the plugin each time the element is clicked, but it seems redundant.

Comment: @epascarello  Don't like the idea of polling.  While I don't know what it is, mutation observers seems really scary!

Comment: well you need to bind it when the dialog opens, that is your only solution than.

Comment: @epascarello  Even if the element in question exists in every handlebar template?

Comment: Maybe when you render the template and attach it to the DOM?

Comment: @Shanimal  Because the template has 1 or 2 elements common to each, and 1 or 2 elements unique to each.

Comment: _"If this answer is plugin specific, please limit to the https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ plugin."_ Not certain you mean ? Are you trying to delegate a plugin instance to an element which does not exist in `document`? Or, only at specific plugin `.editable()`?

Comment: Try @itzmukeshy7's answer. The initial click should bind the plugin here's a gist with modified code.
http://gist.github.com/shanimal/d975416e6e85116bd2a90a43d2401d6a

Comment: @guest271314  I added some context at the end of my original post.

Comment: @user1032531 What is issue with initiating plugin instance when element is appended to `document`? Are you trying to use a single instance of plugin for multiple elements? Does current `javascript` not return expected result?

Comment: @guest271314  I am trying to use a single instance of the plugins for multiple elements of a given class.

Comment: _"I am trying to use a single instance of the plugins for multiple elements of a given class."_ What is purpose of approach? What would `this` be within plugin? Do you mean that you are trying to use a single selector to attach plugin to multiple elements?

Comment: @guest271314  Template 1 has "name", "xxx", and "yyy" xeditable elements.  Template 2 has "name", "aaa", and "bbb" xeditable elements.  Both templates populate `#myDiv`.  The action for "name" for both templates should be identicial.

Comment: What do you mean by _"The action for "name" for both templates should be identicial."_? `$("[data-handler=name]").plugin()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way in JavaScript or jQuery to run some code whenever an element matching a particular selector is added to the DOM.  (Technically, you *can* do this using [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but that's neither particularly simple nor particularly efficient.)

Instead, you have two options:

1. arrange your code to run after the code that inserts the element, or
2. wait until the user *interacts* with the element somehow (e.g. by clicking it, focusing it and/or hovering the mouse over it, all of which trigger events that you can catch) and run your code at that point.

If you're inserting the element yourself (e.g. by calling `$(element).html()` in your own code), then the first option is easy: just add the code to modify the element after the code that inserts it. If, however, the insertion happens asynchronously via some framework whose code you can't easily modify, then you'll need to find some way to hook your code into that framework.

If the framework itself doesn't provide any convenient mechanism for that, one slightly hacky solution may be to find out what method the framework is using internally to insert the element, and hook into that. For example, all jQuery object methods can be modified via the `jQuery.fn` prototype object, so if you e.g. know that the framework is using jQuery `.html()` to insert the element you want to modify, you could do something like this dirty trick:

```
(function  ($) {
    var oldHtml = $.fn.html;
    $.fn.html = function () {
        var rv = oldHtml.apply(this, arguments);
        this.find('a.myClass').editable();
        return rv;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

As a real-world example, I use several variations of both of the techniques described above in my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://github.com/vyznev/soup) user script (which, being a user script, necessarily needs to hook itself into third-party code that may not always have been designed to be hooked into):

- For modifying elements loaded via AJAX, I use a jQuery `ajaxComplete()` hook, which jQuery conveniently provides for running custom code after every AJAX request.
- For other tasks, I also hook into a bunch of jQuery methods as shown above. (I don't actually hook into `.html()`, though.)
- As a fallback, especially for modifying links and other interactive elements, I also set up click and mouseover event handlers (I really should add focus event handlers for keyboard navigation, too) to verify that the modifications have really been applied, and apply them at the last moment if they haven't been.
- Finally, for a couple if particularly tricky tasks, I've also resorted to hooking directly into JS DOM methods and even replacing the entire WebSocket class with my own wrapper. Those are particularly ugly hacks, though, since it's hard to make them robust across different browsers.